# One-file Makefile Problems: C++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, makefile, exe

I've been fiddling with a makefile for the past hour and I can't seem to get it. I need a makefile that will compile main.cpp in /source/ and place the result (e2.exe) in the /build/ folder. Here is what I have right now:

```
build: source/main.cpp
    make -C build/ source/main.cpp
```

I have no idea why it's not working. I have tried soo many things like

```
build: source/main.cpp
    make -o build/ source/main.cpp

build: source/main.cpp
    make -C e2.exe source/main.cpp

build: source/main.cpp
    make -C source/main.cpp e2.exe

build: source/main.cpp
    make source/main.cpp -o e2.exe
```

And lots of other combinations. Here's my folder structure:

```
root/
╚build/
 source/
  ╚main.cpp
 e2.pnproj
 e2.pnps
 Makefile
```

The reason for all the attempts is that nearly every tutorial I come across has complex examples and has everything in a different order.

I think the closest I have come to it working was this:

```
build: source/main.cpp
    make -C build/ source/main.cpp
```

And the error is:

```
make -C build/ source/main.cpp
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/WiiGames/e2/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `source/main.cpp'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/WiiGames/e2/build'
"make": *** [build] Error 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I notice you're `make`ing everything.  At some point, you do have to `cc` (or `gcc`, or whatever) it.  :)

I'd think you could just do like

```
build: source/main.cpp
        $(CXX) -o build/e2.exe source/main.cpp
```

where `$(CXX)` is the name/path to your compiler.  (Note, if you copy/replace, replace those eight spaces with a tab.)

Comment: I have no idea where my compiler is :S I've compiled C++ before, but using a premade example to start with and premade makefile which I can't decode.

Comment: @Stephen: you don't need to know hwere your compiler is. Assuming you've configured your system normally, GNU Make knows to expand `$(CXX)` to the right location.

Comment: For some odd reason, I had to find it and add it to PATH, my Wii program was using something different:

http://www.mail-archive.com/cmake@cmake.org/msg36490.html